# filter numbers with "contains"

Tags: excel, autofilter

I have a list of numbers in my table

```
2029
2032
2033
```

I want to filter by "contains 03" but it does not work this way. It shows as "numbers" when i try to filter this column. I converted all column as General or Text , didnt work. Any ideas ?

Comment: your question is not clear so try to elaborate it

Comment: @akash create a table with 1 column and insert numbers in it. then try to filter with "contains" with custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I'm afraid there is only 1 way to approach this issue, and it's using a helper column:

[image]

I've used a formula on column B to convert numbers to texts:

`=TEXT(A2;"@")`

That way, you can use text filters in second column and filter as you wish:

[image]

There would be another option. If those numbers you type them, instead of typing normal (`2029`), add a single quote at start. Type `'2029`. That way those numbers would be recognized as text, and just 1 column, and you could filter using *contains 03* condition:

[image]

You will know if you type them right because those numbers will be left aligned instead of right aligned. And probably you will see in the left upper corner a symbol, like a little green triangle. That means that number is being recognized as text instead of as a number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i have 14 columns with around 48k rows and i cannot create a helper column for all of them... i also tried to convert them to "@" by vba but it also didnt solve.

Comment: Sorry about that, with the data example you provided I thought it was just a list of numbers. IF you data set is around 48k rows and 14 columns, we are talking about more than 500.000 cells, and using filters on that can consume a  lot of time. I don't know how you need to manage your data, but you should think of using SQL solutions, or Access. Just in case it might be useful for you, an Excel workbook can be a SQL source for another workbook and you can query the data  with the conditions you need. Check http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-relational-data.htm

Comment: thank you, i used Power Query to handle the issue, because normal filtering was taking too much time. but Power Query was also a little slow, therefore i was seeking a faster way... thanks!

Comment: I did a data set of 14 columns and 50000 rows. Each cell contains a different number. Starts at 1 and it ends at 700.000. I did a query to obtain only from column 1 those values that contains 03 and it tooks seconds. Access returned a recordset of more than 2300 records in seconds. Maybe that can work for you because importing/exporting data between Access/Excel is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

if you use conditional formatting you can highlight those that have your value, then use the filter to only show those in this highlighted colour?

E.g. if your data starts in A2 apply conditional formatting to this cell only:
=IF(SEARCH("03",A2)>0,1,0)

Then copy the formatting of this cell to the rest of the data in this column

Repeat for other columns just alter the conditional formatting formula a little.

Hope that helps